# How to use LINQ query with DataGridView but a subset of table columns?

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, strongly-typed-dataset

I am trying to learn from a code example from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but I clearly do not understand the true workings of LINQ. What I wish to do is populate a DataGridView for a "lookup window" with a subset of the available columns in a table from a strongly typed dataset. I am attempting the following:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query = 
            (from t in DataAccess.ds.GL40200.AsEnumerable()
            where t.SGMTNUMB == 3 
            select new { t.SGMNTID, t.DSCRIPTN });

DataTable myTable = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();

dgv_Exhibitors.DataSource = myTable;
```

However, this complains of an implicit conversion error from `EnumerableRowCollection<AnonymousType#1>` to `IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>`.

I tried to add the following, but it results in a runtime error:

```
select new { t.SGMNTID, t.DSCRIPTN }).Cast<DataRow>();
```

While selecting just 't' works, the table contains columns I do not want to show to the user:

```
where t.SGMTNUMB == 3
select t;
```

Can you help with with an easy way to populate the DataGridView with just the two desired columns? If there is a perceived better or easier way than using LINQ I am open to recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because your `select` statement is creating an anonymous class with two fields in it. It's no longer a `DataRow`, nor does the compiler know how to cast it back to a `DataRow` via `Cast<T>()`.

---

One option is to stick with the method that works, then simply hide the columns you don't want to see in the `DataGridView`:

```
dgv_Exhibitors.DataSource =
    DataAccess.ds.GL40200.AsEnumerable().Where(t => t.SGMTNUMB == 3).CopyToDataTable();

foreach (var col in dgv_Exhibitors.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
                                  .Where(c => c.Name != "SGMNTID" && c.Name != "DSCRIPTN"))
{
    col.Visible = false;
}
```

Alternatively, set `AutoGenerateColumns = false` and then just define the columns you want to see and add them to the `DataGridView.Columns` collection.

---

Another option is to use your existing method, but call `ToList()` on it, and don't bother trying to convert it back to a `DataTable`. The `DataGridView` can display any collection:

```
dgv_Exhibitors.DataSource = (from t in DataAccess.ds.GL40200.AsEnumerable()
                             where t.SGMTNUMB == 3 
                             select new { t.SGMNTID, t.DSCRIPTN }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Grant Winney's answer, use [var](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) instead of `IEnumerable <DataRow>` to receive the anonymous types.

```
var query = 
        (from t in DataAccess.ds.GL40200.AsEnumerable()
        where t.SGMTNUMB == 3 
        select new { t.SGMNTID, t.DSCRIPTN });
```

And if you want the results in a Datatable, you'll have to create one and add the values one by one.

```
DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
myTable.Columns.Add("SGMNTID", typeof(int));
myTable.Columns.Add("DSCRIPTN", typeof(string));
foreach (var x in query)
        {
            DataRow dr = myTable.NewRow();
            dr[0] = x.SGMNTID;
            dr[1] = x.DSCRIPTN;
            myTable.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

dgv_Exhibitors.DataSource = myTable;
```